# why are warnings disabled by default in rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

I was surprised to learn that warnings are apparently disabled by default in rake:

```
  def broken_code
    path = '/tmp/foo'

    # create empty file
    File.open(path, 'w')

    # when warnings are enabled you get a warning here- File#new does not take a block
    File.new(path) do |f|
      puts "never get here..."
    end
  end

  task :no_warnings do |t|
    broken_code
  end

  task :warnings do |t|
    $VERBOSE = 1
    broken_code
  end
```

Why are they disabled? Is there a simple way to enable them, beyond setting `VERBOSE=1` early in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me:

```
# Rakefile
task :foo do |t|
  File.new {}
end
```

Result:

```
$ rake foo
(in /tmp)
/tmp/Rakefile:2: warning: File::new() does not take block; use File::open() instead
rake aborted!
```

Comment: Interesting. Mind giving me your rake & ruby version? I'm using rake 10.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.3p362. Thanks

Comment: rake 10.0.4 and Ruby 2.0.0p247 but I get the same results with rake 0.8.7 and Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: OK seems to be because my rake task is defined within a Rails .rake file, rather than a standalone Rakefile. I suppose this is Rails disabling warnings rather than Rake.

Comment: Yes, it is: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks.rb#L1